# jQuery onload event maintaining "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(this).load(function(){
  if ($(this).val()!="") {
    $(this).next().css('display','none');
  }
});
```

I am trying to make a function that hides the element after it if it's value wasn't none,
but when the load event is launched, the "this" keyword now points at "Document" !!
i tried load/ready/bind load
the control doesn't has an ID , what am i missing ...?

Comment: The "load" event is fired for the page (document) as a whole, and for individual `<img>` elements. What sort of element is `this` when you set that up?

Comment: your $(this).load needs to be an element from the DOM

Comment: the "this" is an "input" element

Comment: Well there's no "load" event fired for `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always preserve the value of `this`:

```
var it = this;
$(this).load(function() {
  if ($(it).val() != '') ...
```

Why it might be that you'd assign a "load" handler to some sort of form field element is not clear, however.

Comment: i cant do this because the is call many times... it will be overridden

Comment: i'm running the code as a plugin, it will be invoked foreach control the user want to,